# computations in IEEE754 (single precision) - considerations

Tags: architecture, ieee-754

Now, we are focused on IEEE754 (single precision), let
`x=2^{-64}`
`y=2^{96}`.
What will be result of `x-y` and `y/x`.

I am not sure if I correctly understand this format, however I show you my approach:
`x/y` is fairly easy - it is sufficient to operate on exponents:  `y/x=2^{32}`.

When it comes to `x-y=x+(-y)`.  Now, computer should shift lower number to upper number, to be more detail it should shift fraction by `64+96` in right. Because fraction has only `23` bits the result is:
`x+(-y) = 2^{96} + 0  = 2^{96}`.

Am I ok ?

Comment: Check your numbers. x / y = 2^(-160).

Comment: I edited my post - thanks for detecting mistake.